# What Is This in The Top of IL-86VKP?

Tags: aircraft-design, feature-identification

What Is This in The Top of IL-86VKP?
[image]

Comment: It's an oxygen chamber to keep the exalted leader looking artificially young...

Answer (score 2):

[Ilyushin Il-80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-80)

[image]
<sup>[Source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-80#/media/File:Ilyushin_Il-80_over_Moscow_6_May_2010.jpg)</sup>

The "canoe" is thought to house "advanced" satellite communications equipment. This is a classified aircraft though, so there isn't a lot of publicly available information on exactly what other equipment might be contained in that hump.

Comment: This angle makes that a shockingly unaerodynamic looking hump! It looks like the front is _very_ vertical and not at all smoothly blended into the roof line. Of course, that's topic for a different question, and considering the classified nature of the aircraft, probably an unanswerable one, so I won't bother asking

Comment: @FreeMan Side-on angles may be deceiving. It looks like the front is tapered to cause less drag so it probably isn't a huge impact. It doesn't seem to matter though, the aircraft can stay airborne indefinitely because there seems to be a refueling probe on the nose.

Comment: Good thing about refuling, too, @RonBeyer - those look like very inefficient low-bypass engines! `</OT ramblings>`